# Pandas dataframe change values when it meets dual criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

I have a dataframe which has data as:

```
Run_1   Run_2   Run_3 Avg
5.26    6.08    1.8   2
273     0       0     23  
5.26    6.08    1.8   1
```

It has shape

```
(2928, 501)
```

I want to change all values > 0 to 0 and set all values currently at 0 to 1 for only columns containing sub-string `Run_` in its name. The number of columns is from `Run_1, Run_2, ... Run_500`. The conditional change is not applied to any other column than `Run_1, Run_2, ... Run_500`.

So, desired output is:

```
Run_1   Run_2   Run_3 Avg
0       0        0    2
0       1        1    23  
0       0        0   1
```

I tried the following:

```
    maxGen = np.max(df.filter(regex='Run_').values) + 5555.
    df.loc[df.filter(regex='Run_') > 0] = maxGen
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 500 to array axis with dimension 2928
```

Edit:
There are no negative values in dataframe.

Comment: Change all positive values to zero, what about negatives, are negative values possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.assign(**df.filter(like='Run_').eq(0).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   Run_1  Run_2  Run_3  Avg
0      0      0      0    2
1      0      1      1   23
2      0      0      0    1
```

Or if you don't like the "**" unpacking use join:

```
df.filter(like='Run_').eq(0).astype(int).join(df['Avg'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Transform should work

```
df[[x for x in df.columns if 'Run_' in x]] = df[[x for x in df.columns if 'Run_' in x]].transform(lambda x: x.eq(0).astype(int))
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
df.iloc[:,:-1]=(~df.astype(bool)).astype(int)
df
Out[54]: 
   Run_1  Run_2  Run_3  Avg
0      0      0      0    2
1      0      1      1   23
2      0      0      0    1
```